# Swift: Animated UIView moves towards source instead of away from it

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I seriously looked around here but didn't find something that would answer my question, so if you found a right solution, please tell me.

So: I wrote a little app in Xcode in which two labels should move from there current position to a another position 350 points above. I animated them like this:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0 , animations: {            
    self.label1.center.y += CGFloat(-350)
    self.label2.center.y += CGFloat(-350)
})
```

What actually happened was, that as soon as this line was hit, the labels jumped 350 points down and then moved the 350 points up to their source. When I changed the `CGFloat` value to +350, the labels jumped up 350 points, and then moved down back to source again. So it seems, instead of starting the animation from the source, Xcode tried to make the animation go to the source. I honestly do not have a clue why, as all the documentation about animation suggest otherwise.

BTW I also looked, whether I had a constraint on the y-placement of the labels, but there weren't any.

Comment: I tested the code in my simulator and these label just moved away instead of moving back.

Comment: where you put the code

Comment: Can you provide more code? There's nothing wrong with the lines you provided, so the problem must be somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try:

```
self.label1.center.y += CGFloat(-350)
self.label2.center.y += CGFloat(-350)
```

Then:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0 , animations: {
    layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

**Note:** If you use constraints for labels you should change your labels' positions by changing their constraints instead of adding `CGFloat` to it. Then try:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0 , animations: {
    layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked for me, though I had to enter self.view.layoutIfNeeded() or else the compiler wouldn‘t accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to move the center of the view which is kind of bad practice, you can try the following code in you animation block

`self.label2.transform =    CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0, y: 350)`

This will actually animate the layer and not the actual frame of the view.